# What is the type for array of different modules in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-components, angular-module

In angular 5 core module I'm importing external and internal modules as well.

So, I created an array of type `any` to hold all module objects. I used that array variable in imports and exports. My question is instead of `any` is there are other types we have? If So, for MODULES and COMPONENTS what type should come?

```
const MODULES: any[] = [
  BrowserModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  RouterModule,
];

const COMPONENTS: any[] = [
  HeaderComponent
];

const PROVIDERS: Provider[] = [
  NotifyService,
  RouterHelpers
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...MODULES,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...COMPONENTS,
  ],
  providers: [
    ...PROVIDERS
  ],
  exports: [
    ...MODULES,
    ...COMPONENTS,
  ]
})

export class CoreModule {
}
```

Comment: If you look at the `NgModule` interface, the angular team used `Array<Type<any> | any[]>;` for component declarations and `Array<Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders | any[]>;` for module imports.

Comment: @David giving type any for MODULES, COMPONENTS is valid?

Answer (score 2):

from [NgModule](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule) doc

- Provider type is `Provider[]`
- Declarations type is  `Array<Type<any> |any[]>`
- Imports type is  `Array<Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders |any[]>`
- Exports type is  `Array<Type<any> | any[]>`
- EntryComponents type is  `Array<Type<any> | any[]>`

Answer (score 1):

Using type `any[]` for modules and components is valid.  If you want to use something else, you can refer to the [`NgModule`](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule) interface, which uses

- `Array<Type<any> | any[]>;` for component declarations
- `Array<Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders | any[]>;` for module imports

`Type` is a class from the angular framework ([doc](https://angular.io/api/core/Type))